# How can I shorten the "if else" event?

Tags: c#

how can I Write this as short as possible? here are many more conditions.
The purpose of the code below is to calculate the total price and display it as a message, adding the price of each selected hardware to the determined base price to the Calculate button click event.

( sorry for bad english :/ )

```
decimal tabanFiyat = 500;
decimal cpuFiyat = 0;

if (rbCpuI7.Checked)
  cpuFiyat = 300;
else if (rbCpuI5.Checked)
  cpuFiyat = 200;
else if (rbCpuI3.Checked)
  cpuFiyat = 100;
else if (rbCpuR5.Checked)
  cpuFiyat = 250;
else if (rbCpuR3.Checked)
  cpuFiyat = 150;

tabanFiyat += cpuFiyat;

decimal ramFiyat = 0;

if (rbRam16.Checked)
  ramFiyat = 125;
else if (rbRam8.Checked)
  ramFiyat = 75;
else if (rbRam4.Checked)
  ramFiyat = 45;

tabanFiyat += ramFiyat;
```

Comment: Put the radio buttons into an array

Comment: they have different values ​​but?

Comment: Check if there is something like a `RadioButtonList` control available for your UI Framework (which you forgot to reveal to us...). It should have a single `SelectedIndex` or `SelectedItem` value which you can then use.

Comment: If I add it to arrays won't it take longer?

Comment: Most radio button controls I've encountered allow you to associate a value for each radio button (like the numeric values you have).  That would solve the "different values" part.  As for "take longer" -- readability is more important than performance until it isn't, and I'm pretty sure you're a long, long way from that point.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can work:

```
cpuFiyat = (rbCpuI7.Checked)? 300: 
           (rbCpuI5.Checked)? 200:
           (rbCpuI3.Checked)? 100:
           (rbCpuR5.Checked)? 250:
           (rbCpuR3.Checked)? 150: 0;

tabanFiyat += cpuFiyat;
decimal ramFiyat;
ramFiyat = (rbRam16.Checked)? 125:
           (rbRam8.Checked)?   75:
           (rbRam4.Checked)?   45: 0;

tabanFiyat += ramFiyat;
```

Comment: thanks!!! this saved me....

Answer (score 1):

Assuming those are radio buttons

```
  var radList = new List<(RadioButton, int)> {
      (rbCpuI7,300),
      (rbCpuI5,200)
      .....
   };

   var chck = radList.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Item1.Checked);
   rbCpuI5 += chk.Item2;
```

if nothing is checked you will get 0

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the .Checked property comes from some UI, the framework is likely to expose an "onChecked" event so the event handler should assign the correct value, and uncheck others if mutually exclusive. But you'd need to provide more details.